# Excel Unique Identification Formula Stops Working

Tags: excel

I have been attempting to use a formula that will create a unique identifier for each part description so I can easily reference them in another worksheet.  I found the following formula and was able to use it successfully, but only for the first 695 unique part descriptions.  After that, it stops working and returns #N/A for the remaining 3000 part descriptions in the worksheet.

Here is the current formula, along with a visual of the issue:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B30,B29:$B$29,0)),MAX(C29:$C$29)+1,VLOOKUP(B30,B29:C29,2,FALSE))
```

[image: Part Descriptions]

The data was all exported from the same system so I can't imagine a difference there.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `MATCH(B30,B29:$B$29,0)` was correct at the top of the list then it should be `VLOOKUP(B30,B$29:C29,2,FALSE)` at the top of the list.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much!